# viewing the population? (sql server full text search)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I'm thinking that when we are working on full text search, we might want to view how sql server FT engine breaks the data and indexes it. For my case the column being indexed are simple nvarchar strings with spaces (no punctuation).

I'd want to be able to take the "tokens" out. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: By "tokens" do you mean stoplist words, or something else? Do you just mean you want to pull all of the words out and count occurrences? Per row or for the whole table? What exactly do you mean by "viewing the population"?

Comment: Tokens = individual words in a sentence when we break it. For e.g take string `deception point`. Tokens you'get are `deception` and `point`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to be having a look at the Full Text DMVs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174971%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Specifiably I think you want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(db_id('AdventureWorks2012'), object_id('HumanResources.JobCandidate'))
GO
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(db_id('AdventureWorks2012'), object_id('HumanResources.JobCandidate'))
GO
```